# Can I possibly put an image/label into an option box in Tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter, label, optionmenu

I don't know if it's possible to achieve something Like this:

[ Sunrise ↕]
Î
(Preferably an image resized into a label)

Comment: by label do you mean text? you can put text in option box

Comment: @acw1668: I don't think that's true. An optionmenu is just a menubutton and a menu, and a menu item can have both text and images. It might take some extra work, but it's not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

The `OptionMenu` doesn't directly support it, but the `OptionMenu` is just a `Menubutton` and a `Menu`. You can iterate over the menu and add images after creating the widget.

Here's a simple example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

image1 = tk.PhotoImage(width=16); image1.put('red', to=(0,0,15,15))
image2 = tk.PhotoImage(width=16); image2.put('green', to=(0,0,15,15))
image3 = tk.PhotoImage(width=16); image3.put('blue', to=(0,0,15,15))
images = {"red": image1, "green": image2, "blue": image3}

colorvar = tk.StringVar(value="red")
om = tk.OptionMenu(root, colorvar, "red", "green", "blue")
menu = om.nametowidget(om.menuname)
for label, image in images.items():
    print(f"configuring {label}")
    menu.entryconfigure(label, image=images[label], compound="left")

om.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]